# Adobe Media Server and the Authentication Add-In

Tags: flash-media-server

The Authentication Add-In (used to authenticate Adobe Live Media Encoders connecting to FMS) will not install with Adobe Media Server 5.0 because it looks for Flash Media Server and does not recognise Adobe Media Server.

Is there a workaround or a new version of the Authentication Add-In?

Answer (score 1):

I posted the question to Adobe's forums. An Adobe staff member responded with "We were able to reproduce the issue and are looking into it. Currently we do not have any workaround for this issue. We'll get back to you with an update at the earliest."

Comment: A new version has been release which works with Adobe Media Server 5. https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=fmle3